# Loop a column value in a table using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I hope you are fine!
I'm new in coding so I'm facing of something without results.
I have this type of code here in JS.

```js
key: 'generateChart2',
value: function generateChart2() {
    var self = this;
    var Jahr1 = [];

    var years1 = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#mf123_select_jahr').val().length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) years1 += ","
        years1 += $('#mf123_select_jahr').val()[i];
    }
    var postedData1 = {};
    postedData1.years1 = years1;
    console.log(postedData1);

    $.ajax({
        url: "data/json.dashboard.php?call=chart2",
        data: postedData1,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (dataGraph2) {
 
            var trHTML='';

            $.each(dataGraph2, function (key, value) {

                for (var i in postedData1) {
                    Jahr1.push(postedData1[i].years1);
                }
                console.log(postedData1.years1);
                                    
                trHTML += 
                        '<tr><td >' + value.Mandant + 
                        '</td><td >' + thousandSepNeu(value.Jahr1, 2) + " €" +
                        '</td><td >' + value.Growth +
                        '</td></tr>';
            });

            $('#dataGraph2').append(trHTML);
        }

    });

}
```

The `value.Mandant` and the `value.Growth` are doing well. The problem that I have is that the `for` loop does not work. I need to thr `postedData1` to choose whenever the user choose the year to show him the results.

The output of console.log(postedData1); is:

[image]

Am I making a mistake? I know that the problem is on the `for` loop.

Please any advice i would appreciate it.
:)

Comment: what is `mf123_select_jahr` ? Also,which for loop are you talking about please elaborate ?

Comment: mf123_select_jahr is the ID of a multiple selector of a dropdown menu and when the user click to a year then it shows the results. So this year, I take it and I insert this to an array postedData1. now I want these results to push them into the table you see.

Comment: Can you show `mf123_select_jahr` ?  Also what this gives you `console.log(postedData1);` show output of that . Currently , your question doesn't have much information please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I attached the screenshot of console.log

Comment: So you need to add that value i.e: `2020,2019` in `Jahr1` array  ?

Comment: Yeah that's right!

Comment: Hi check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1bzw50tq/) fiddle that should work .